# How to serialize List within object without annotation?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have JSON that looks something like this (the full JSON is much larger):

```
{
    "legalLastName": "lastName",
    "legalFirstName": "firstName",
    "terminationDate": null,
    "collegeEducation": [{
        "major": "Finance",
        "school": "Towson University",
        "quarter": null,
        "degreeType": "B.S.",
        "yearEarned": "1990",
        "degreeLevel": "Undergraduate"
    }]
}
```

How do I use the ObjectMapper to apply custom serialization to `collegeEducation`? I can't use the annotation `JsonSerializer`, because the POJO is generated, and that library doesn't provide a way to apply that annotation. So I'd like to use the default ObjectMapper serialization for all fields but the list.

Comment: You should be able to use Mixin or Custom Serializer for this use case.

Comment: Please show your POJO, partial is OK.

Answer (score 0):

#### Objective: A field in Education named as `degreeType` will be serialized to json field `degree`

## Mixin or Custom serializer can be used

#### Student and Education class

Lets define the Student and Education class as follows

```java
static class Education {
  String major;
  String degreeType;
}

static class Student {
  String legalLastName;
  String legalFirstName;
  List<Education> educationList;
}
```

## Mixin

Use mixin to define a parallel class with updated field specifications

#### Mixin class for Education

1. Define the field in the actual object `String degreeType;`
2. Add the custom field name to be serialized to `@JsonProperty("degree")`

```java
abstract class EducationMixin {
  @JsonProperty("degree")
  String degreeType;
}
```

#### Configure ObjectMapper with Mixin

1. Enable field visibility(as the class does not have getter/setter)
2. Register the education mixin

```java
static void withMixin(Student student) throws Exception {
  ObjectMapper studentMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  studentMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
  studentMapper = studentMapper.addMixIn(Education.class, EducationMixin.class);
  System.out.println(studentMapper.writeValueAsString(student));
}
```

## Or Custom Serializer

Custom serializer's can be used to serialize java objects.

#### Add custom serializer for Education

Add the custom serializer class to Serialize Education

```java
static class EducationSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Education> {
  @Override
  public void serialize(Education education, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
    throws IOException {
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField("major", education.major);
    gen.writeStringField("degree", education.degreeType);
    gen.writeEndObject();
  }
}
```

#### Initialize ObjectMapper with necessary configuration

1. Enable field visibility(as the class does not have getter/setter)
2. Register the education serializer

```java
static void withCustom(Student student) throws Exception {
  ObjectMapper studentMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  studentMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
  SimpleModule studentModule = new SimpleModule();
  studentModule.addSerializer(Education.class, new EducationSerializer());
  studentMapper.registerModule(studentModule);
  System.out.println(studentMapper.writeValueAsString(student));
}
```

Full working code

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MixinTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.legalFirstName = "first";
        student.legalLastName = "last";

        Education education = new Education();
        education.degreeType = "degreetypevalue";
        education.major = "majorvalue";
        student.educationList = new ArrayList<>();
        student.educationList.add(education);

        withMixin(student);
        withCustom(student);
    }

    static void withMixin(Student student) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper studentMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        studentMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        studentMapper = studentMapper.addMixIn(Education.class, EducationMixin.class);
        System.out.println(studentMapper.writeValueAsString(student));
    }

    static void withCustom(Student student) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper studentMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        studentMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        SimpleModule studentModule = new SimpleModule();
        studentModule.addSerializer(Education.class, new EducationSerializer());
        studentMapper.registerModule(studentModule);
        System.out.println(studentMapper.writeValueAsString(student));
    }

    static class Education {
        String major;
        String degreeType;
    }

    static class Student {
        String legalLastName;
        String legalFirstName;
        List<Education> educationList;
    }

    abstract class EducationMixin {
        @JsonProperty("degree")
        String degreeType;
    }

    static class EducationSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Education> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Education education, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField("major", education.major);
            gen.writeStringField("degree", education.degreeType);
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```